# Why does direct linear transform (DLT) yield a unique solution?

Tags: systems-of-equations, triangulation

I try to triangulate point correspondences from 2 images in order to reconstruct the 3D positions of those points.
I found the DLT method as an easy way to achieve that. The system which needs to be solved is shown [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E16385/s17/Slides/11.4_Triangulation.pdf) on page 23

[image]

whereas $\mathit{x}, \mathit{y}, \mathit{x'}, \mathit{y'}$ are the projected image points,$\pmb{p_i^T}$ are the rows of the 3x4 camera matrix P. Having 2 point correspondences from two views leads to the matrix $A$. So the matrix $A$ is a 4x4 matrix. What we want to find is the 3D point $X$ which is in homogeneous coordinates. According to the literature a unique solution for this can be found using SVD.
But I don't understand why a unique solution for $X$ can be found at all. Since this is a homogeneous linear system, it should either have the trivial solution $X=\overrightarrow{0}$ or infinitely many. What am I missing here?

Comment: I did not read the book, but homogeneous coordinates notoriously represent a point by a line. Which is logical, because we add a dimension (3D $\rightarrow$ 4D). So finding a dim 1 solution space is not a surprise.

Comment: Well but then A should possess a 1-dimensional null-space and X can only be determined up to a non-zero scale factor (infinitely many solutions). So no unique solution.

Comment: Yes, precisely. When representing a point in $n$ dimensions by homogeneous coordinates in $n+1$ dimensions, those homogeneous coordinates are up to a non-zero scale factor. A point is represented by a line. Cf. this Wikipedia page : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates : "If homogeneous coordinates of a point are multiplied by a non-zero scalar then the resulting coordinates represent the same point".

Comment: I understand. So the 4th component of X is a scaling factor right?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Note that this representation has the additional benefit that you can represent points at infinity: these are points where this 4th component is zero. In this geometry, all conics (ellipse, parabola, hyperbola) are the same closed curve.

Comment: Thanks. Do you want to give an answer to this question? Then I mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Transforming my comments into an answer)
When representing a point in $n$ dimensions by homogeneous coordinates in $n+1$ dimensions, those homogeneous coordinates are up to a non-zero scale factor. A point is represented by a line. Quoting [Wikipedia page on homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates): "If homogeneous coordinates of a point are multiplied by a non-zero scalar then the resulting coordinates represent the same point".

In this representation, one of the coordinates, e.g. the 4th, can be taken as a scaling factor.

Representation by homogeneous coordinates has various benefits, in addition to simplifying computation of camera projections; notably one can represent points at infinity (projective geometry): these are points where the 4th coordinate is zero. In this geometry, all conics (ellipse, parabola, hyperbola) are the same closed curve.